# Contributor disable seeing others' posts

Tags: user-roles

How can I disallow contributors on my site from seeing what other posts are published on the site, and only see their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are talking about wp-admin section. If yes just place this code in your `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'posts_for_current_contributor' );
function posts_for_current_contributor() {
    global $user_ID;

    if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
       if ( ! isset( $_GET['author'] ) ) {
          wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'author', $user_ID ) );
          exit;
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Giri: Thanks for the answer but it's not perfect yet.

Admin can modify the query arg "author" manually and they will be able to view the other

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET['author'] ) ) {
```

The line above should also check if $_GET['author'] is not current user

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, like accepted answer (but without redirection):

```
    function posts_for_current_author ($query) {
        if( $query->is_admin && 'edit.php' == $GLOBALS['pagenow'] && !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
            $query->set('author', $GLOBALS['user_ID'] );
        }
        return $query;
    };
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```